# Dados sendo apagados do banco h2 com Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2database

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação com Spring Boot e utilizando o banco H2.

Quando eu cadastro uma pessoa, ela fica com id 1, se eu cadastro outra pessoa fica com o id 2 e por ai vai, só que se eu reinicio o banco eu perco tudo e a primeira pessoa que eu cadastro volta a ter id 1 e por ai vai, eu queria que continuasse como id 3, 4.

Tem algum jeito de deixar salvo os dados no banco H2?

Meu `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb  
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver  
spring.datasource.username=sa  
spring.datasource.password=password  
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Para utilizar sem ser em memoria você pode optar por mariaDB Mysql ou Postgresql, quando os dados são salvos em memoria o intuito é que eles não fiquem salvos após o termino da execução, entretanto eles podem ser utilizados enquanto seu servidor/container estiver na execução atual.

Comment: O problema é que você especificou `h2:` **`mem`** `:testdb`. É isso que está fazendo ficar em memória. Use a opção `file` com `AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE` - Eu havia convertido as respostas em comentário, mas tive que reverter o processo (são respostas, mas aparentam incorretas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que li na documentação:

- http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases
- http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url

você esta usando explicitamente o modo in-memory, conforme isso:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

O **`mem:`** indica esse modo, "memory".

Para persistir basta não usar esse modo `mem:`, o H2 tem dois meios de trabalhar:

### [Local (**Embedded connection**)](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases):

Exemplos:

```
jdbc:h2:[file:][<caminho>]<banco de dados>
jdbc:h2:~/exemplo
jdbc:h2:file:/data/exemplo
jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/exemplo (apenas Windows)
```

### [Remoto (**Server mode**)](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server)

Exemplos (o que também permite temporário):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://<server>[:<porta>]/[<caminho>]<banco de dados>
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/exemplo
jdbc:h2:tcp://dbserv:8084/~/exemplo
```

Se for remoto e temporário também usa o **mem:**:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:exemplotemporario
```

Em resumo, o H2 não é apenas usado em memória